# Regex para consecutivos y duplicados

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, regex

Estoy buscando una regex para validar en un campo telefono de 10 digitos,

Consecutivo = 123456789
Duplicados de bloques de a 4 = 4545-4545 (sin el guion)

Me podrian dar una mano?

Gracias!

Comment: No queda muy claro con los ejemplos que pones qué es lo que quieres hacer.  ¿Podrías poner algunos ejemplos de teléfonos válidos y no válidos y detallar un poco más la duda?

Answer (score 0):

Hola debes implementar una máquina de pila. Pues las expresiones regulares no tienen memoria debido a que solo obedecen una tabla de trancisiones.

Sin embargo puedes hacer trampa usando agrupadores:

Por ejemplo:

> ((?< token1>[0-9]+)(?< simbolo>[-])?)

Yo he usado c# para cosas similares, pero lo correcto es hacer la máquina de estados con memoria.

REF 1. En clase de compiladores eso es lo primero que enseñan cuando se comparan automátas vs autómatas de pila.
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aut%C3%B3mata_con_pila

REF 2. Mira como queda con rubular
https://rubular.com/r/lYOszG2ALUTell

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]